# If Command Exists, Call Function, Else Write-Host Message

Tags: powershell

I know you can use Get-Command to check whether a cmdlet exists. However, assume that you have hundreds of cmdlets that you would be checking whether they exist. As part of this existance check, if the cmdlet exists, it is executed (in the below example, call the cmdlet and just export the results to csv). If the cmdlet doesn't exist, a message is written via Write-Host. An example is provided below.

```
 if (Get-Command "Get-HostedOutboundSpamFilterPolicy" -errorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {
        Get-HostedOutboundSpamFilterPolicy | Export-Csv "C:\HostedOutboundSpamFilterPolicy.csv" -NoTypeInformation 
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Get-HostedOutboundSpamFilterPolicy Not Found"
    }
```

Is it possible to write this more efficiently to avoid the ugly/long if/else?

Comment: Hi there! You seem to have forgotten to ask a question :)

Comment: Specific question added, :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of command names you can simply loop over them:

```
# Could be $commands = Get-Content commands.txt
$commands = "Get-HostedOutboundSpamFilterPolicy","Get-HostedInboundSpamFilterPolicy","SomeOtherCmdlet"

foreach($commandName in $commands){
  if($command = Get-Command $commandName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
    & $command |Export-Csv "${commandName}.csv"
  }
  else {
    Write-Host "$commandName not found!"
  }
}
```